# PostgreSQL interpolation based on jsonb

Tags: postgresql

I currently have data of the following form:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_table (
    id1 text,
    id2 text,
    data jsonb
);
INSERT INTO sample_table (id1, id2, data)
VALUES
    ('row1', 'abc', '[[0.1, 1.0, 0.2], [0.2, 2.0, 0.4], [0.3, 3.0, 0.6], [0.4, 4.0, 0.8]]'::jsonb),
    ('row2', 'def', '[[0.2, 1.5, 0.3], [0.3, 2.5, 0.5], [0.4, 3.5, 0.7], [0.5, 4.5, 0.9]]'::jsonb),
    ('row3', 'ghi', '[[0.3, 1.2, 0.4], [0.4, 2.2, 0.6], [0.5, 3.2, 0.8], [0.6, 4.2, 1.0]]'::jsonb);
```

Each row is uniquely identified by id1 and id2. I want to use an arbitrary value of 2.5 to check the second element of each array: e.g. it falls inbetween 2.0 and 3.0 in the first row as seen by the array: [0.2, 2.0, 0.4], [0.3, 3.0, 0.6]. Based on the distance of 2.5 to 2.0 and 2.5 to 3.0 I want to linearly interpolate using the values of 0.4 and 0.6 (e.g. 0.4 + ((3.0-2.5)/(3.0-2.0))*0.6 = 0.5).

```
0.4 + 0.5*(0.6-0.4) = 0.5
0.5 + 0*(0.7-0.5) = 0.5
0.6 + 0.3*(0.8-0.6) = 0.66
```

I want to write a query that gives me id1, id2, and the interpolated value as shown in the above code snippet. Hereby also how I expect the output to look like:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_table_output (
    id1 text,
    id2 text,
    data float
);

INSERT INTO sample_table_output (id1, id2, data)
VALUES
    ('row1', 'abc', 0.5::float),
    ('row2', 'def', 0.5::float),
    ('row3', 'ghi', 0.66::float);
```

Thanks so much,

Guyon

Comment: Sorry, I don't get how the interpolation examples relate the values in your example or the "input value 2.5". Can you clarify?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to write a query? What is the expected output?

Comment: Hey Bergi,

what I basically want to do is the following. I want to use my value of 2.5 to check the second element of each array: e.g. it falls inbetween 2.0 and 3.0 in the first row as seen by the array: [0.2, 2.0, 0.4], [0.3, 3.0, 0.6]. Based on the distance of 2.5 to 2.0 and 2.5 to 3.0 I want to linearly interpolate using the values of 0.4 and 0.6 (e.g. 0.4 + ((3.0-2.5)/(3.0-2.0))*0.6 = 0.5).

Thanks so much for your quick response.

Comment: I have also edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Do your arrays ***have*** to be JSONB? It's generally a bad idea as all you're going to do is repeatedly translate them to virtual tables *(more complex code repeated across multiple queries, repeated redundant effort, lack of type safety, lack of constraints, etc, etc)*.

Comment: The current example has only a few arrays but this could in practice be 40 per row, hence the reason to put them in this format. If you have any alternatives, please let me know as I am still learning.

Comment: I would approach the maths this way: I would multiply each value by their weighting and then add them together. So: `(0.4 * 0.5) + (0.6 * 0.5) = 0.2 + 0.3 = 0.5` and `(0.5 * 1) + (0.7 * 0) = 0.5 + 0 = 0.5)` and `(0.6 * 0.7) + (0.8 * 0.3) = 0.42 + 0.24 = 0.66`

Comment: What if your arbitrary value is lower than the lowest array value, or higher than the highest array value? Exclude that row? Return NULL for the interpolated value? Return the nearest array elements value?

Comment: Return a NULL indeed, sorry for not specifying.

Comment: As a test case, it would probably be good to have an example in the question where the value in the array was over 2.5 (e.g. 2.7), so that you would then have to look at the index before for your other value. All the examples in the question look at a cell and the one after it, but never the one before it.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
  normalised AS
(
  SELECT
    id1,
    id2,
    (data_rows->0)::NUMERIC(8,4)  AS y_min,
    (data_rows->1)::NUMERIC(8,4)  AS x,
    (data_rows->2)::NUMERIC(8,4)  AS y_max
  FROM
    sample_table
  CROSS JOIN
    jsonb_array_elements(sample_table.data)
      AS data_rows

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    id1,
    id2,
    NULL,
    -9999.9999, -- fence post value for minus infinity for x
    NULL
  FROM
    sample_table
),
  look_forward AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    LEAD(x    ) OVER w   AS x_next,
    LEAD(y_max) OVER w   AS y_max_next
  FROM
    normalised
  WINDOW
    w AS (
      PARTITION BY
        id1, id2
      ORDER BY
        x
    )
)
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON (id1, id2)
  id1,
  id2,
  
  x      AS x_prev,
  y_max  AS y_prev,
  
  2.5    AS x_sample,
  y_max
   +
  ((2.5 - x) / (x_next - x))
   *
  (y_max_next - y_max)
    AS y_linearly_interpolated,

  x_next,
  y_max_next   AS y_next
FROM
  look_forward
WHERE
  x <= 2.5
ORDER BY
  id1, id2, x DESC
```

| id1 | id2 | x_prev | y_prev | x_sample | y_linearly_interpolated | x_next | y_next |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | abc | 2.0000 | 0.4000 | 2.5 | 0.500000000000000000000000 | 3.0000 | 0.6000 |
| row2 | def | 2.5000 | 0.5000 | 2.5 | 0.500000000000000000000000 | 3.5000 | 0.7000 |
| row3 | ghi | 2.2000 | 0.6000 | 2.5 | 0.660000000000000000000000 | 3.2000 | 0.8000 |
| row4 | ghi | -9999.9999 | *null* | 2.5 | *null* | 4.2000 | 0.4000 |
| row5 | ghi | 2.4000 | 1.0000 | 2.5 | *null* | *null* | *null* |

[working example on dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/eJEBBLCo)

This transforms your json into usable data, then for each array looks forward to the next array, in order to find the "ranges", then does the calculation.

Comment: Could you explain what the UNION all here does?

Comment: The DISTINCT ON plus the ORDER BY plus the WHERE clause can find the "latest" row "on or before" the arbitrary value of 2.5. Which means that if the arbitrary value is less than the lowest value in the data, nothing is found. The UNION ALL creates one more row per (id1, id2) that starts from "negative infinity", to ensure that at least one row is always found (allowing NULLs to be returned). I've created a modified fiddle to make it a bit more obvious... https://dbfiddle.uk/FqrSjFb8

Comment: That makes sense let me try this out

Comment: Note ; I just corrected the final calculation slightly.